# How to filter products on Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm working with **[Amazon Product Advertising API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html)** as I said in the title. I'm trying to find a way to have a better product filtering. **I know** (and I tested that) the classic filters method as by **using keywords**, **Nodes** or **PowerSearch**.

What I'm searching right now is how to make a **deep search in a specific branch**.

For example, on Amazon Websites is possible filtering Laptops by their **RAM size, Weight, Hard Drive Type** (check the image for a better understand) and a lot of other things.

**Is it possible** to have the same filtering opportunities by using Amazon Product Advertising API (and I miss to read the resources) or not?

If not, there is **some other way** to accomplish this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not everything seen on amazon.com is exposed via APIs.

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/localevalues.html) for supported categories for [USA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/LocaleUS.html) only following search filters are available for `ItemSearch` operation:

```
Author 
Availability 
Brand 
ItemPage 
Keywords
Manufacturer 
MaximumPrice 
MerchantId 
MinPercentageOff 
MinimumPrice 
Sort 
Title
```

I recommend you fetch few items of type you're interested in, see the value of `Keywords` on them. Perhaps you can use that to filter.

Comment: I already tried to use `Keywords` for filtering but is still not enough for what I'm trying to do. I was hoping for a workaround or that I was missing some part of the doc but as I can see from the people that answer (just you LOL) it's impossible to have a better filtering system by using API. What I would like to accomplish is actually possible just by scraping Amazon website that is unfortunately illegal. Anyway thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice Try recording network from Chrome developer tools and do a search on amazon.com. See if there is hidden/undocumented API you can [mis]use.

Comment: This is possible too, I will search and if I will find something about I'll post here a comment in a way that you can update your answer. (I still don't think that use a hidden API is legal  LOL)